# I need a form submit to call a php function with input variables (taken from the form)

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a PHP function that takes in 3 variables and uses them.

```
<?php
function securePayPost($cardnumber, $expiry, $cvv) {
//do stuff with $cardnumber, $expiry and $cvv
?>
```

I have a form where a user can input the card number, expiry, cvv and a few other things:

```
<form action="" method="post" class="form-signin">
   <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Processing Payment</h2>
   <table width="491" border="0">
      <tr>
         <td width="154">Name on card:</td>
         &nbsp;
         <td width="206"><input type="text" name="cardname" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Name on Card" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Card Number:</td>
         &nbsp;
         <td><input type="text" name="creditcard" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Credit Card" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Expiry Date:</td>
         <td>
            <select class="form-control" name="ExpMon" title="select a month">
               <option value="1">Jan</option>
               <option value="2">Feb</option>
               <option value="3">Mar</option>
               <option value="4">Apr</option>
               <option value="5">May</option>
               <option value="6">June</option>
               <option value="7">July</option>
               <option value="8">Aug</option>
               <option value="9">Sept</option>
               <option value="10">Oct</option>
               <option value="11">Nov</option>
               <option value="12">Dec</option>
            </select>
            <select class="form-control" name="ExpYear" title="select a year">
               <option value="2015">2015</option>
               <option value="2016">2016</option>
               <option value="2017">2017</option>
               <option value="2018">2018</option>
               <option value="2019">2019</option>
               <option value="2020">2020</option>
            </select>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <tr>
         <td>CVV:</td>
         <td><input type="text" name="CVV" class="input-block-level" placeholder="CVV" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit">Submit Payment</button></td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td width="129"><button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit" formaction="deliveryDetails.html">Review Details</button></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</form>
```

And the only knowledge I have about how to do this uses the following code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
securePayPost(creditcard, ExpYear, CVV);
}
```

However the issue is that it doesn't know what creditcard, `ExpYear` and `CVV` is. What is the best way for me to do what I want to do?

In short, I want the credit card number, the expiry and the `cvv` to be trapped on form submit, and then fed into the php function `securePayPost` as the variables `$cardnumber`, `$expiry` and `$cvv`.

Comment: This will get you on your way: `securePayPost( $_POST['creditcard'], $_POST[ExpYear'] . '-' . $_POST[ExpMon'], $_POST['CVV']);` A question: What format should $expiry be? A year-month string like "2015-08" or "8/15"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well just get those values an pass to the function -

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    //get values from form
    $creditcard = $_POST['creditcard'];
    $ExpYear = $_POST['ExpYear'];
    $CVV = $_POST['CVV'];

    //pass to the function
    securePayPost($creditcard, $ExpYear, $CVV);
    }
```

Comment: Where exactly would I put this?

Comment: well in your form submission script.... mention that page in your form action field and put the code inside that page....

Answer (score 0):

No need to declare variables for post values just do the following and you will get the same result with less code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
securePayPost($_POST['creditcard'], $_POST['ExpYear'], $_POST['CVV']);
}
```

Comment: Where would I put this?

Comment: @bandoy123 in the place where you wanna run your function. lets say you have a functions.php and index.php you include functions.php on your index.php and just use the above php code in functions.php

Answer (score 0):

Your form use method POST, so you can retrive values in $_POST array.
So you can do somthing like this :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])
{
      if(isset($_POST["cardname"])) {$cardname=$_POST["cardname"];}
      if(isset($_POST["creditcard"])) {$cardnumber=$_POST["creditcard"];}
      if(isset($_POST["cardname"])) {$ExpMon=$_POST["ExpMon"];}
      if(isset($_POST["cardname"])) {$ExpYear=$_POST["ExpYear"];}
      if(isset($_POST["CVV"]))  {$CVV=$_POST["CVV"];}

}
```

Then you can use these variables as you want.
Remember that you have to pass to the function securePayPost() $ExpYear and $ExpMon. Otherwise you have to concatenate $ExpYear and $ExpMon in $expiry just do this:

```
$expiry=$ExpYear.$ExpMon;
```

You know the first two characters is the Expiry Year and the next the Expiry Month.

Otherwise you don't need to declare variables for $_POST array.
You can also pass to your function directly from $_POST[] doing something like this :

```
securePayPost($_POST['creditcard'], $_POST['ExpYear'], $_POST['CVV']);
```

But remember that you need also to pass the $ExpMon or is useless in your form.